# Do I need to iterate through every row of data to calculate time per column category?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

I have list of data in python that looks like the table below.

Basically, it's generated from observing what our robot is doing in our maze/arena. We have timestamps for events, at the moment the timestamps are event driven and not periodic.

I need to find the time spent in each arena in an efficient way.

```
TimeStamp   Arena
101         Arena A
109         Arena A
112         Arena B
113         Arena A
118         Arena A
120         Arena D
125         Arena D
129         Arena D
138         Arena B
139         Arena B
148         Arena C
149         Arena C
150         Arena B
151         Arena B
159         Arena D
169         Arena D
171         Arena D
172         Arena D
175         Arena B
177         Arena B
180         Arena B
181         Arena A
182         Arena A
189         Arena E
200         Arena E
204         Arena E
208         Arena A
209         Arena A
```

Basically, I need to get this below. The total time spent in each arena.

```
 Arena  TimeStamp
Arena D         32
Arena B         23
Arena E         22
Arena A         16
Arena C         10
```

I wrote a simple script that does this right now.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('arenas_visited.csv')


l = len(data[[1]])
first_arena = data.loc[0, 'Arena']
start_time = data.loc[0, 'TimeStamp']

summary = []

for i in range(0,l):

try:
    next_arena = data.loc[i+1, 'Arena']
except:
    break     

first_arena = data.loc[i, 'Arena']   

if first_arena != next_arena:

    change_time = data.loc[i, 'TimeStamp']
    time_spent = change_time - start_time
    arena = str(data.loc[i, 'Arena'])
    summary.append([arena, time_spent])
    start_time = change_time
    first_arena = data.loc[i+1, 'Arena']   

    if i == l-2:
        if data.loc[i, 'Arena'] != data.loc[i+1, 'Arena']:
            time_spent = 1
            arena = str(data.loc[i+1, 'Arena'])
            print (str(1) + " Spent in " + arena)
            summary.append([arena, time_spent])

else:
    pass

aggregated = pd.DataFrame(summary, columns = ['Arena', 'TimeStamp'])
time_per_arena = aggregated.groupby(['Arena']).sum().sort_values('TimeStamp',  ascending=False).reset_index()
print time_per_arena
```

Basically, while this works fine enough. However, I'll eventually have literally millions of lines of this data and I need to figure out a faster way to do this.

However, I don't see any other way of doing this other than iterating through every row?

Is something I'm not considering?

Comment: If all you need is a summary by arena, why aren't you just calculating that?

Comment: I need to get the differences in time stamps, grouping them doesn't work because then i can't tell which is entering or leaving a room.

Answer (score 2):

Create the vector of time deltas, then group and sum against it:

```
df['delta'] = df.TimeStamp - df.TimeStamp.shift()

df.groupby('Arena').delta.sum()
Out[62]: 
Arena
Arena_A    21.0
Arena_B    23.0
Arena_C    10.0
Arena_D    32.0
Arena_E    22.0
Name: delta, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This looks potentially useful. Did you run it against my data or is this just a sample? Because the answers are different. I've found some bugs in mine, but I'll test this method and let you know if this worked. Thanks Boud!

Comment: A simple copy paste of your data above. The math you're trying to accomplish in a vectorized way is what I describe to you. I didn't read your code because your explanations of what you try to accomplish are enough.

Comment: The 5 missing probably corresponds to 208 and 209 that would likely raise the exception in your code and do break. You don't consider that limit in your code, when you calculate by hand it s 21. This is a good illustration you should not take a for loop in rows approach, as it is very slow and error prone. The rule of thumb is when you work with data frames, find always the vector math logic behind what you try to calculate. For loop is last resort evil solution.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a bunch of *nice things* that other languages don't built in automatically. There is no reason to index through data yourself when you can:

```
result = {}
old_arena = None
old_timestamp = 0
# I don't have a lot of experience with panda, so you may need to massage the 
# input to be able to do this
for line in data:
    timestamp, _, arena = line.split()
    if arena == old_arena:
        continue
    timestamp = int(timestamp)
    try:
        result[old_arena] += timestamp - old_timestamp
    except:
        result[old_arena] = timestamp - old_timestamp

    old_arena = arena
    old_timestamp = timestamp

# Process the last interval - if the last one was changed, then
# old_timestamp will equal timestamp and this is fine    
result[old_arena] += int(timestamp) - old_timestamp
```

This will process the entire list a single time with `O(n)` time & `O(n+k)` space complexity, where k is the number of arenas.

The result with be a dict containing (where the None represents the initial time offset):

```
{'A': 27, 'C': 2, 'B': 26, 'E': 19, 'D': 34, None: 101}
```

In the case of your example data: It's worth noting that this gives the transitions to the old_arena, which may not be what you wanted.

---

If you want it where transitions go to the next arena, a minor edit will provide that by reversing our traversal:

```
result = {}
old_arena = None
old_timestamp = 0
# I don't have a lot of experience with panda, so you may need to massage the 
# input to be able to do this
for line in reversed(data):
    timestamp, _, arena = line.split()
    if arena == old_arena:
        continue
    timestamp = int(timestamp)
    try:
        result[old_arena] += old_timestamp - timestamp
    except:
        result[old_arena] = old_timestamp - timestamp

    old_arena = arena
    old_timestamp = timestamp

# Process the last interval - if the last one was changed, then 
# old_timestamp will equal timestamp and this is fine    
result[old_arena] += old_timestamp - int(timestamp)
```

Which gives:

```
{'A': 21, 'C': 10, 'B': 23, 'E': 22, 'D': 32, None: -209}
```

Comment: Very interesting solution. Testing it now!

Comment: @StacyGarfield I added the reverse solution: where transitions go to the new arena.

Comment: @StacyGarfield I've fixed a bug that prevented it from adding the last interval